# strange characters when getting the fingerprint key for android using CMD

Tags: android

[image]

This is the input and output of my keytool execution.

Comment: According to [these docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_exportcert) the `-exportcert` command, without `-file certfilename` will write the (binary) certificate to _stdout_ (i.e. the screen). So that's exactly what one would expect.

Comment: what should I do in this command.

Comment: this command is working well when getting hashkey for facebook integration keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Yousry\.android\debug.keystore | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64

Comment: but when getting fingerprint for google integration using this command ,require password =android     keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Yousry\.android\debug.keystore

Comment: I  guess you either need to add `-file mycert.cert` to the command-line to write the certificate to a file or pipe it into an `openssl` command as in your 2nd comment.